# How can i create a point to point connection?

Tags: networking, pptp, pptpd

We have a measurement campaign in a field, until now we had the following network structure
[image]

The distance was 400m between the two points so the most easy solution was to use a Wifi pont to point bridge connection. The PC with the 192.168.0.10 IP act as a server, and run a software which controls the other PC. In this network structure all PC had the same subnet and it was easy to establish TCP/UDP(Broadcasting, unicasting) connections.

From now on the distance between the two point is 20km, so the wifi solution is not working any more. In this case we have the following network structure:
[image]

My question is how can I establish a point to point connection through internet, to get the same structure as in the first image? For example where I still can broadcast and unicast through UDP etc.

### Edited

I know only the VPN server IP, so from the PC with the 13x.xxx.xxx.xxx IP can connect to the VPN server, therefore that PC will be in the same subnet(192.168.1.0/24). 
For example, there will be eth0 with 13x.xxx.xxx.xxx IP and tun0 with 192.168.1.22, in this case can I run a VPNServer on that PC so the PC with the 192.168.1.21 IP can establish a VPN Bridge connection?

Comment: setup a site to site vpn ?

Comment: It looks like what you want is to set your VPN for layer 2 bridging... except that your VPN server is in a different network entirely (192.168.1.x).

Comment: I don't have access to the VPN server, so I can't modify the settings,but I can connect to this VPN server

Comment: Um, what?  You don't have access to the VPN server... so your job would be, what, exactly?

Comment: Yes, because this is an university network, they are providing only the access to the VPN server.

Comment: I've never dealt with anything like this but you should be able to set up your own pair of VPN servers supporting layer 2 bridging and NAT-Traversal in 192.168.0.x, and having your VPN traffic go over the university's VPN.  You'll have to deal with small MTU (each encapsulation reduces the amount of data that can go in a packet) and the university's VPN may not accept non-TCPIP traffic, but I think it may be possible if you control 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get site 2 a permanent, reliable internet connection and use a permanent site to site VPN. You'll need a router each side capable of doing so, though.